# Integrating bpmn-js to modeler the react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bpmn.io

I have been trying to integrate the [bpmn-js modeler](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js) to the react component, but has been unable to get any result. Can anyone help me with there code? All the requirement have already done. It would be very much helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I've created a small component who loads the library seems to be working ok, maybe you been trying to implement it not using the React Life Cycle, is really important to know how this work to achieve the results most of the libraries use the dom element, and the element is only available after render so I've used componentDidMount to ensure that.

Here's the basic demo:
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KnHgXtsXlkcJJo735S4

Component example:

```
import React from 'react'
import BpmnViewer from 'bpmn-js'

class bpmnView extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
  super();
    this.viewer = new BpmnViewer();
    this.generateId = 'bpmnContainer'+ Date.now();
  }
  render(){
    return <div id={this.generateId}></div>;
  }
  componentDidMount (){
    this.viewer.attachTo('#'+ this.generateId);

      // import function
  function importXML(xml,Viewer) {

    // import diagram
    Viewer.importXML(xml, function(err) {

      if (err) {
        return console.error('could not import BPMN 2.0 diagram', err);
      }

      var canvas = Viewer.get('canvas'),
          overlays = Viewer.get('overlays');


      // zoom to fit full viewport
      canvas.zoom('fit-viewport');

      // attach an overlay to a node
      overlays.add('SCAN_OK', 'note', {
        position: {
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0
        },
        html: '<div class="diagram-note">Mixed up the labels?</div>'
      });

      // add marker
      canvas.addMarker('SCAN_OK', 'needs-discussion');
    });
  }


  // a diagram to display
  //
  // see index-async.js on how to load the diagram asynchronously from a url.
  // (requires a running webserver)
  var diagramXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<definitions xmlns=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL\"\r\n             xmlns:bpmndi=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI\"\r\n             xmlns:omgdc=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC\"\r\n             xmlns:omgdi=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI\"\r\n             xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\r\n             expressionLanguage=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath\"\r\n             typeLanguage=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\r\n             targetNamespace=\"\"\r\n             xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/20100501/BPMN20.xsd\">\r\n<collaboration id=\"sid-c0e745ff-361e-4afb-8c8d-2a1fc32b1424\">\r\n    <participant id=\"sid-87F4C1D6-25E1-4A45-9DA7-AD945993D06F\" name=\"Customer\" processRef=\"sid-C3803939-0872-457F-8336-EAE484DC4A04\">\r\n    </participant>\r\n</collaboration>\r\n<process id=\"sid-C3803939-0872-457F-8336-EAE484DC4A04\" isClosed=\"false\" isExecutable=\"false\" name=\"Customer\" processType=\"None\">\r\n    <extensionElements/>\r\n    <laneSet id=\"sid-b167d0d7-e761-4636-9200-76b7f0e8e83a\">\r\n        <lane id=\"sid-57E4FE0D-18E4-478D-BC5D-B15164E93254\">\r\n            <flowNodeRef>sid-D7F237E8-56D0-4283-A3CE-4F0EFE446138</flowNodeRef>\r\n            <flowNodeRef>sid-52EB1772-F36E-433E-8F5B-D5DFD26E6F26</flowNodeRef>\r\n            <flowNodeRef>SCAN_OK</flowNodeRef>\r\n            <flowNodeRef>sid-E49425CF-8287-4798-B622-D2A7D78EF00B</flowNodeRef>\r\n            <flowNodeRef>sid-E433566C-2289-4BEB-A19C-1697048900D2</flowNodeRef>\r\n            <flowNodeRef>sid-5134932A-1863-4FFA-BB3C-A4B4078B11A9</flowNodeRef>\r\n        </lane>\r\n    </laneSet>\r\n    <startEvent id=\"sid-D7F237E8-56D0-4283-A3CE-4F0EFE446138\" name=\"Notices&#10;QR code\">\r\n        <outgoing>sid-7B791A11-2F2E-4D80-AFB3-91A02CF2B4FD</outgoing>\r\n    </startEvent>\r\n    <task completionQuantity=\"1\" id=\"sid-52EB1772-F36E-433E-8F5B-D5DFD26E6F26\" isForCompensation=\"false\" name=\"Scan QR code\" startQuantity=\"1\">\r\n        <incoming>sid-4DC479E5-5C20-4948-BCFC-9EC5E2F66D8D</incoming>\r\n        <outgoing>sid-EE8A7BA0-5D66-4F8B-80E3-CC2751B3856A</outgoing>\r\n    </task>\r\n    <exclusiveGateway gatewayDirection=\"Diverging\" id=\"SCAN_OK\" name=\"Scan successful?&#10;\">\r\n        <incoming>sid-EE8A7BA0-5D66-4F8B-80E3-CC2751B3856A</incoming>\r\n        <outgoing>sid-8B820AF5-DC5C-4618-B854-E08B71FB55CB</outgoing>\r\n        <outgoing>sid-337A23B9-A923-4CCE-B613-3E247B773CCE</outgoing>\r\n    </exclusiveGateway>\r\n    <task completionQuantity=\"1\" id=\"sid-E49425CF-8287-4798-B622-D2A7D78EF00B\" isForCompensation=\"false\" name=\"Open product information in mobile  app\" startQuantity=\"1\">\r\n        <incoming>sid-8B820AF5-DC5C-4618-B854-E08B71FB55CB</incoming>\r\n        <outgoing>sid-57EB1F24-BD94-479A-BF1F-57F1EAA19C6C</outgoing>\r\n    </task>\r\n    <endEvent id=\"sid-E433566C-2289-4BEB-A19C-1697048900D2\" name=\"Is informed\">\r\n        <incoming>sid-57EB1F24-BD94-479A-BF1F-57F1EAA19C6C</incoming>\r\n    </endEvent>\r\n    <exclusiveGateway gatewayDirection=\"Converging\" id=\"sid-5134932A-1863-4FFA-BB3C-A4B4078B11A9\">\r\n        <incoming>sid-7B791A11-2F2E-4D80-AFB3-91A02CF2B4FD</incoming>\r\n        <incoming>sid-337A23B9-A923-4CCE-B613-3E247B773CCE</incoming>\r\n        <outgoing>sid-4DC479E5-5C20-4948-BCFC-9EC5E2F66D8D</outgoing>\r\n    </exclusiveGateway>\r\n    <sequenceFlow id=\"sid-7B791A11-2F2E-4D80-AFB3-91A02CF2B4FD\" sourceRef=\"sid-D7F237E8-56D0-4283-A3CE-4F0EFE446138\" targetRef=\"sid-5134932A-1863-4FFA-BB3C-A4B4078B11A9\"/>\r\n    <sequenceFlow id=\"sid-EE8A7BA0-5D66-4F8B-80E3-CC2751B3856A\" sourceRef=\"sid-52EB1772-F36E-433E-8F5B-D5DFD26E6F26\" targetRef=\"SCAN_OK\"/>\r\n    <sequenceFlow id=\"sid-57EB1F24-BD94-479A-BF1F-57F1EAA19C6C\" sourceRef=\"sid-E49425CF-8287-4798-B622-D2A7D78EF00B\" targetRef=\"sid-E433566C-2289-4BEB-A19C-1697048900D2\"/>\r\n    <sequenceFlow id=\"sid-8B820AF5-DC5C-4618-B854-E08B71FB55CB\" name=\"No\" sourceRef=\"SCAN_OK\" targetRef=\"sid-E49425CF-8287-4798-B622-D2A7D78EF00B\"/>\r\n    <sequenceFlow id=\"sid-4DC479E5-5C20-4948-BCFC-9EC5E2F66D8D\" sourceRef=\"sid-5134932A-1863-4FFA-BB3C-A4B4078B11A9\" targetRef=\"sid-52EB1772-F36E-433E-8F5B-D5DFD26E6F26\"/>\r\n    <sequenceFlow id=\"sid-337A23B9-A923-4CCE-B613-3E247B773CCE\" name=\"Yes\" sourceRef=\"SCAN_OK\" targetRef=\"sid-5134932A-1863-4FFA-BB3C-A4B4078B11A9\"/>\r\n</process>\r\n<bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id=\"sid-74620812-92c4-44e5-949c-aa47393d3830\">\r\n    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement=\"sid-c0e745ff-361e-4afb-8c8d-2a1fc32b1424\" id=\"sid-cdcae759-2af7-4a6d-bd02-53f3352a731d\">\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"sid-87F4C1D6-25E1-4A45-9DA7-AD945993D06F\" id=\"sid-87F4C1D6-25E1-4A45-9DA7-AD945993D06F_gui\" isHorizontal=\"true\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"250.0\" width=\"933.0\" x=\"42.5\" y=\"75.0\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-84cb49fd-2f7c-44fb-8950-83c3fa153d3b\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"59.142852783203125\" width=\"12.000000000000014\" x=\"47.49999999999999\" y=\"170.42857360839844\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"sid-57E4FE0D-18E4-478D-BC5D-B15164E93254\" id=\"sid-57E4FE0D-18E4-478D-BC5D-B15164E93254_gui\" isHorizontal=\"true\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"250.0\" width=\"903.0\" x=\"72.5\" y=\"75.0\"/>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"sid-D7F237E8-56D0-4283-A3CE-4F0EFE446138\" id=\"sid-D7F237E8-56D0-4283-A3CE-4F0EFE446138_gui\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"30.0\" width=\"30.0\" x=\"150.0\" y=\"165.0\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-e0502d32-f8d1-41cf-9c4a-cbb49fecf581\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"22.0\" width=\"46.35714340209961\" x=\"141.8214282989502\" y=\"197.0\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"sid-52EB1772-F36E-433E-8F5B-D5DFD26E6F26\" id=\"sid-52EB1772-F36E-433E-8F5B-D5DFD26E6F26_gui\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"80.0\" width=\"100.0\" x=\"352.5\" y=\"140.0\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-84cb49fd-2f7c-44fb-8950-83c3fa153d3b\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"12.0\" width=\"84.0\" x=\"360.5\" y=\"172.0\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"SCAN_OK\" id=\"SCAN_OK_gui\" isMarkerVisible=\"true\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"40.0\" width=\"40.0\" x=\"550.0\" y=\"160.0\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-e0502d32-f8d1-41cf-9c4a-cbb49fecf581\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"12.0\" width=\"102.0\" x=\"521.0\" y=\"127.0\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"sid-E49425CF-8287-4798-B622-D2A7D78EF00B\" id=\"sid-E49425CF-8287-4798-B622-D2A7D78EF00B_gui\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"80.0\" width=\"100.0\" x=\"687.5\" y=\"140.0\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-84cb49fd-2f7c-44fb-8950-83c3fa153d3b\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"36.0\" width=\"83.14285278320312\" x=\"695.9285736083984\" y=\"162.0\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"sid-E433566C-2289-4BEB-A19C-1697048900D2\" id=\"sid-E433566C-2289-4BEB-A19C-1697048900D2_gui\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"28.0\" width=\"28.0\" x=\"865.0\" y=\"166.0\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-e0502d32-f8d1-41cf-9c4a-cbb49fecf581\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"11.0\" width=\"62.857147216796875\" x=\"847.5714263916016\" y=\"196.0\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement=\"sid-5134932A-1863-4FFA-BB3C-A4B4078B11A9\" id=\"sid-5134932A-1863-4FFA-BB3C-A4B4078B11A9_gui\" isMarkerVisible=\"true\">\r\n            <omgdc:Bounds height=\"40.0\" width=\"40.0\" x=\"240.0\" y=\"160.0\"/>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNShape>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement=\"sid-EE8A7BA0-5D66-4F8B-80E3-CC2751B3856A\" id=\"sid-EE8A7BA0-5D66-4F8B-80E3-CC2751B3856A_gui\">\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"452.5\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"550.0\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement=\"sid-8B820AF5-DC5C-4618-B854-E08B71FB55CB\" id=\"sid-8B820AF5-DC5C-4618-B854-E08B71FB55CB_gui\">\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"590.0\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"687.5\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-e0502d32-f8d1-41cf-9c4a-cbb49fecf581\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"12.048704338048935\" width=\"16.32155963195521\" x=\"597.8850936986571\" y=\"155\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement=\"sid-7B791A11-2F2E-4D80-AFB3-91A02CF2B4FD\" id=\"sid-7B791A11-2F2E-4D80-AFB3-91A02CF2B4FD_gui\">\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"180.0\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"240.0\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement=\"sid-4DC479E5-5C20-4948-BCFC-9EC5E2F66D8D\" id=\"sid-4DC479E5-5C20-4948-BCFC-9EC5E2F66D8D_gui\">\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"280.0\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"352.5\" y=\"180\"/>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement=\"sid-57EB1F24-BD94-479A-BF1F-57F1EAA19C6C\" id=\"sid-57EB1F24-BD94-479A-BF1F-57F1EAA19C6C_gui\">\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"787.5\" y=\"180.0\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"865.0\" y=\"180.0\"/>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>\r\n        <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement=\"sid-337A23B9-A923-4CCE-B613-3E247B773CCE\" id=\"sid-337A23B9-A923-4CCE-B613-3E247B773CCE_gui\">\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"570.5\" y=\"200.0\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"570.5\" y=\"269.0\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"260.5\" y=\"269.0\"/>\r\n            <omgdi:waypoint x=\"260.5\" y=\"200.0\"/>\r\n            <bpmndi:BPMNLabel labelStyle=\"sid-e0502d32-f8d1-41cf-9c4a-cbb49fecf581\">\r\n                <omgdc:Bounds height=\"21.4285888671875\" width=\"12.0\" x=\"550\" y=\"205\"/>\r\n            </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>\r\n        </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>\r\n    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>\r\n    <bpmndi:BPMNLabelStyle id=\"sid-e0502d32-f8d1-41cf-9c4a-cbb49fecf581\">\r\n        <omgdc:Font isBold=\"false\" isItalic=\"false\" isStrikeThrough=\"false\" isUnderline=\"false\" name=\"Arial\" size=\"11.0\"/>\r\n    </bpmndi:BPMNLabelStyle>\r\n    <bpmndi:BPMNLabelStyle id=\"sid-84cb49fd-2f7c-44fb-8950-83c3fa153d3b\">\r\n        <omgdc:Font isBold=\"false\" isItalic=\"false\" isStrikeThrough=\"false\" isUnderline=\"false\" name=\"Arial\" size=\"12.0\"/>\r\n    </bpmndi:BPMNLabelStyle>\r\n</bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>\r\n</definitions>\r\n\r\n";

  // import xml
  importXML(diagramXML, this.viewer);


  }
}


export default bpmnView
```

Comment: Hi, @diegochavez.
Could you improve example with any bpmn flow?

Comment: @galkin take a look the demo please, I just added some basic functionality with diagram display.

Comment: You made an amazing example!

Comment: Don't forget to detach it with `componentWillUnmount(){this.viewer.detach()}`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know 'how', is to read [the official doc](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/modeler) and [its code](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/blob/master/modeler/app/app.js#L9-L14).

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import BpmnModeler from "bpmn-js/lib/Modeler";

import "bpmn-js/dist/assets/diagram-js.css";
import "bpmn-js/dist/assets/bpmn-js.css";
import "bpmn-js/dist/assets/bpmn-font/css/bpmn-embedded.css";

import "./styles.less";

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const modelerRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    modelerRef.current = new BpmnModeler({
      container: canvasRef.current
    });
    modelerRef.current.createDiagram();
    return () => {
      modelerRef.current.destroy();
    };
  }, []);
  return <div ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} />;
}
```